# How can I get the exit code of the covered executable from the DotCover console runner?

Tags: msbuild, nunit, code-coverage, dotcover

My organization is working on integrating DotCover's console runner (described [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/running-code-coverage-from-the-console-with-dotcover) and [here](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/07/running-code-coverage-from-the-console-with-dotcover)) into our MSBuild-based build process via a custom MSBuild task.

As you might expect, we are covering NUnit runs over our unit test assemblies.  While we are quite happy with the coverage results DotCover is generating, we've discovered that our tests can now fail without causing our build to fail.  One step forward, two steps back.

DotCover (at least the way we are running it) completely hides the results of the covered process, both the console output and the exit code.  I wish it behaved more like NCover in this regard -- echoing all output and the exit code from the covered process.

Does anyone know how to achieve either of these with the DotCover console runner?  Getting the exit code of the covered process is most important, as we need our builds to fail in the event of a test failure.

Comment: If someone with high enough rep answers this question, can I suggest a dotcover tag get created?  There are several questions on SO that reference it.

Comment: could you go around and retag the mentioned questions, for future reference?

Comment: @GregC - thanks, I've added this tag to the dotcover questions I could find

Answer (score 1):

We are using MSBuild and MSBuild Community Tasks to fail the build.

You can analyze the dotCover generated output xml file using the XmlRead task of MSBuild.CommunityTasks.

```
<Target Name="DetermineCoverage">
    <Message Text="==================================================" />
    <Message Text="Determine Unit Test Coverage" />

    <XmlRead
        XPath="/Root/@CoveragePercent"
        XmlFileName="dotCoverOutput.xml">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="CoveragePercent"/>
    </XmlRead>
    <Message Text="==" />
    <Message Text="== Coverage Percentage $(CoveragePercent)" />

    <Error
        Text="Unit Test coverage did not exceed the desired threshold"
        Condition="$(CoveragePercent) &lt; 90" />

    <Message Text="==================================================" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

An alternative workaround is to run your unit tests with your test runner outside of dotCover first. This will expose the correct return codes.

And then as a second step, run dotCover to get your coverage results.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed a workaround quickly, I've added a post-processing step to scrape the NUnit xml file generated during the DotCover run for test case failures, and I fail the build if I find any.  I did this via a simple custom MSBuild Task:

```
public class CheckNUnitResults : Task
{
    [Required]
    public string ResultFile { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        Log.LogMessageFromText("Analyzing nunit results : " + ResultFile, MessageImportance.Normal);
        var failedCases =
            XDocument
                .Load(ResultFile)
                .Descendants("test-case")
                .Where(xe => xe.Attribute("success").Value.Equals("False"));
        var fail = failedCases.Any();
        if (fail)
        {
            Log.LogError("Found test case failures : " +
                         string.Join(", ", failedCases
                                               .Select(xe => xe.Attribute("name").Value)
                                               .ToArray()));
        }
        return !fail;
    }
}
```

This is called from MSBuild thusly:

```
<CheckNUnitResults ResultFile="YourNUnitResultFile.xml" />
```

(I call it in a loop over an ItemGroup containing my result files)